# MySQL order by date strange prob

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I has been working in a updation of a existing website. In that there was a entry form which will save in table... table structure and sample data as follows

```
id  |  name       | type    |  in_date     |  year   
-----------------------------------------------------
1   |  name1      | 1       |  2-July      |  2011
2   |  name2      | 2       |  2-June      |  2011
3   |  name44     | 2       |  8-Sep       |  2011
```

Now I need to order this table in whole date wise ie ( as 2-June-2011) as a simple query

```
SELECT * FROM order_list order by date DESC
```

Is any way to do this action ? I tried a lot of query .... Any way to combine these 2 rows ..

We cant alter the DB since it contains more existing records ..

Comment: thanks for the reply ... it was an existing db .. it contains 4 years of data .. any way ?

Comment: Are you really using MySQL server and also using Microsoft SQL server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should store your dates as MySQL [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) types, rather than as strings:

```
ALTER TABLE order_list ADD COLUMN new_date DATE;

UPDATE order_list
SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(in_date, '-', year), '%e-%b-%Y');

ALTER TABLE order_list DROP COLUMN in_date, DROP COLUMN year;
```

Ordering then becomes trivial (i.e. will work exactly as you have attempted):

```
SELECT * FROM order_list ORDER BY date DESC;
```

If you're unable to alter the database schema, you can perform the [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) operation in the `ORDER BY` clause (but this is not very efficient):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     order_list
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(in_date, '-', year), '%e-%b-%Y') DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Put the entire date in one column, and then, if you really have to, create computed columns that will hold the year or day/month.

You can create a simple script that will integrate those two existing columns into the one united-date column in your existing database.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `+` (SQL SERVER) or `CONCAT` (MySQL)

```
SELECT * FROM order_list order by in_date + year DESC
```

Comment: Won't this result in a lexicographic ordering?